# Stop IntelliJ from generating @Override on interface implementations?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is it possible to stop IntelliJ Idea from generating the `@Override` annotation on generated interface implementations?

I'm interested in not having to manually delete these annotations whenever they're generated because I generate them often and it's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The option for changing that is at `Settings | Code Style | Java | Code Generation | Insert @Override annotation`

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm aware of this option, but this disables the @Override for *all* overriden methods. I only want to disable it for interfaces.